# Select where not exists with: multiple select queries & concat query & join query

Tags: mysql, sql

I am currently struggling to run a query that can select values that don't exists.

This is the current code I have, that matches the two tables together and shows the result table that I need.

```
select * from (select innerb.pcode, (select concat(innerb.barcode, 
innerb.checkd)) as x from innerb) innerb join wms on wms.barcode = innerb.x and 
innerb.pcode like '%101'
```

but how would I implement a select where not exists based on the code above.

Code here:

```
(select innerb.pcode, (select concat(innerb.barcode, 
innerb.checkd)
```

basically returns the completed value that matches to the column I have joined with another table.

this is what I have tried so far:

```
select * from (select innerb.pcode, (select concat(innerb.barcode, 
innerb.checkd)) as x from innerb) innerb where not exists (join wms on 
wms.barcode = innerb.x) and innerb.pcode like '%101'
```

Comment: update your question add  a proper data sample and the expetced  result

Comment: i have fiddle link for it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems you need like below `notexists`

```
select a.* 
from  wms    a where not exists
  ( 
   select 1 from innerb  b where a.barcode=concat(b.barcode,b.checkd)
  )
```

output

```
id  pcode      barcode
2   5013548     505050
```

Comment: this is the value is should show `("5013548", "505050");` from the wms table

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ff20d48eca3d58c62949fa4b10239e4f this is the query that returns that exists, but i want to reverse it to not exists. just not sure where this code goes `WHERE NOT EXISTS`

Comment: @Eduards https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=f0f830628b319af9fd67f8b53d5e7582

Comment: wms.pcode: "5013548", wms.barcode "505050" this should be the end result as this doesent exist inside innerb

Comment: @Eduards so you 5013548,505050 in output ?

Comment: yeah @Zaynul Abadin Tuhin

Comment: @Eduards https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=456179f6b810b68db42b6a3e6d1560c4 check this link

Comment: PERFECT!! Thanks for your time

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190497/discussion-between-zaynul-abadin-tuhin-and-eduards).